# Limit of two sequences V(n) and U(n)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$U(n)$ and $V(n)$ are sequences. $U(n)> 0$  and   $V(n) >0$ such that: ${V(n+1)\over V(n)}≤ {U(n+1)\over U(n)}$.

Prove that:

1. If $\,\,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} V(n)= +\infty\,\,$ then $\,\,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}  U(n) = +\infty$
2. If $\,\,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} U(n) = 0 \,\, $  then  $\,\,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} V(n) = 0$

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Stop reposting the same question, this is misusing the site.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\log v_{n+1} - \log v_n \le \log u_{n+1} - \log u_n$, hence summing gives
$\log v_{n} - \log v_1 \le \log u_{n} - \log u_1$, or, equivalently
${v_n \over v_1} \le {u_n \over u_1}$ (and implicitly, $0 \le {v_n \over v_1}$).

The answers to 1,2 follow immediately from this.

Comment: How we can know that the limit of u(1) or v(1) isnt infinity ?

Comment: What does that mean, the limit of $u_1$ or $v_1$? I thought these were sequences of positive numbers?

Comment: I mean U(1) or V(1) can't equal infinity ?

Comment: I don't know how to divide infinities, so you will have to elaborate your question a bit.

Comment: instead of log , we can use ln ?

Comment: You can use any $\log$ you want, they are all related by constants. In fact, you don't need logs, you could just multiply the corresponding inequalities since they are all non negative and avoid $\log$s entirely. However, I think $\log$s makes it a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $\left( \frac{V_n}{U_n} \right)$ is decreasing and bounded below, therefore convergent to some $c > 0$. There exists $N$ such that for $n\ge N$,

$$\frac{V_n}{U_n} - c < 1$$

For $1)$, we have for $n\ge N$, $U_n > \frac{V_n}{c+1}$, therefore $U_n \to \infty$.

For $2)$, we have for $n\ge N$, $0 < V_n < (c+1)U_n$. So $V_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

(i) given $M \in \mathbb{R}$ there exist an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that forall $n \geq  \mathbb{N}$ will imply $V(n) > M \frac{1}{U(1)}$. We now take the ratio which will give us

$$\frac{V(n)}{V(1)} \leq\frac{U(n)}{U(1)}$$
which gives us $U(n) \geq M$.  Hence the first one.

(ii) given $\epsilon >0$ there exist an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that forall $n \geq  \mathbb{N}$ will imply $U(n) < \epsilon \frac{1}{V(1)}$. Then 
$$\frac{V(n)}{V(1)} \leq\frac{U(n)}{U(1)}$$ gives us
$$V(n) < \epsilon$$